# Syntax error on CREATE TABLE SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, create-table

What is wrong with the sql? I don't know what is wrong. It keeps giving me    syntax errors.

```
$dbh->exec ("CREATE TABLE 'test'
             (col1 CHAR (64) PRIMARY KEY,
             col2 CHAR (64),
             col3 CHAR (64),
             col4 CHAR (64))") or die (print_r ($dbh->errorInfo (), true));
```

I'm using EasyPHP, just installed it. I'm trying to create a table using the code above. This is the error it returning. I tried correcting the syntax many times. I honestly think the syntax is correct. Is something to do with the configuration of my EasyPHP installation like maybe mysql configured incorrectly.

Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 )

Edit: 
Here is the code i'm using to connect:

```
function dbConnect ($dbname) {
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = new PDO ("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    if ($db) {
        //echo "Connected to database." . "</br>";
    }

    return $db;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what the stack trace looks like?

Comment: Can you also post the code you are using to connect to the database?

Comment: you got some advance, see the answers, don't forget check one as correct ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I still haven't gotten to work.

Comment: Has anyone figured out the problem yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your SQL to:

```
CREATE TABLE test
             (col1 CHAR (64) PRIMARY KEY,
             col2 CHAR (64),
             col3 CHAR (64),
             col4 CHAR (64))
```

Try with:

```
$dbh->exec ("CREATE TABLE test
             (col1 CHAR (64) PRIMARY KEY,
             col2 CHAR (64),
             col3 CHAR (64),
             col4 CHAR (64))") or die (print_r ($dbh->errorInfo (), true));
```

Comment: It got rid of the error message. But when I check the database in phpadmin, the table is nonexistent.

Comment: @agentNil try to execute the query in phpmyadmin and see what happens

Comment: @agentNil do you got some advance?

Comment: What do you mean got some advance?

Comment: No, still don;t know why? Does this normally work? I'm not doing something i'm not suppose to am I? If that is the case, it should narrow down the possible problems to configuration and not the code itself.

Comment: @agentNil can you edit your question with the actual state of the problem?

Comment: The state hasn't changed it is still the same. I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Table names don't go inside quotes, change

```
CREATE TABLE 'test'
             ^    ^
```

To

```
CREATE TABLE `test`  // don't even need back ticks usually
```

Comment: That's what I had before.

Comment: If you had that before then there would not be any syntax error, with that change your query works just fine.

Comment: I've tried playing around with the quotes, backticsk, but doesn't work.